# two parametric equations of a regular curve

Tags: vector-analysis

Are there any relation between two parametric equations of a regular curve? For example, let $\alpha : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\beta : [c,d] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the parametric equations of a regular curve $C.$ Is there a $C^1$ function $\phi : [a,b] \to [c,d]$ such that $\alpha =\beta \circ \phi?$ [Or $\phi$ is differentiable and $\phi'$ is integrable on $[a,b]?$]

It seems that the existence of $C^1$ function $\phi$ is not guaranteed, but I would be thankful for any comments about this question.

Answer (score 0):

Except at stationary or multiple points of the curve, $\beta$ is invertible and you can write

$$v=\beta^{-1}(\alpha(u))=\phi(u)$$

Then

$$\alpha(u)=\beta(\phi(u)).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is $\phi$ $C^1$-function ?

Comment: Probably, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are.

Comment: It seems that it's right, but I don't know the exact reason for it. Do you know any theorem to guarantee it?

Comment: Apply the chain rule and the inverse function theorem carefully to prove it. For that to work, it's essential that $\beta$ is not only invertible, but that its derivative is never zero. To see that this is necessary, consider the parameterizations $t \mapsto t$ and $t \mapsto t^3$, both parameterizing the interval $-1 < x < 1$ (with $-1 < t < 1$ as the domain).) In this case, $\phi$ becomes $t \mapsto t^{\frac{1}{3}}$, whose "derivative" at $0$ is infinite.

Comment: How can I apply Inverse function theorem to prove it?  I think it's for the function where domain and image  have the same dimension. Am I missing something?